# Group same tags with space

Tags: xslt-1.0

I would like to know the XSLT pattern for the below sample.

Input

```
<root>
<p>Sample data 1</p>
<data>1</data>
<data>2</data>
<data>3</data>
<data>4</data>
<p>Sample data 2</p>
<p>Sample data 3</p>
<data>a</data>
<data>b</data>
<data>c<i>d</i>e</data>
<data>d</data>
<p>Sample data 4</p>
</root>
```

Required Output:

```
<root>
<p>Sample data 1</p>
**<data>1 2 3 4</data>**
<p>Sample data 2</p>
<p>Sample data 3</p>
**<data>a b c<i>d</i>e d</data>**
<p>Sample data 4</p>
</root>
```

I want to group the tag `"<data>"` with space inside the `"<data>"` for the entire XML file. There might be many occurence of `"<data>"` tag in single file.

Thanks,
Muthu

Comment: Is there any way to alter the XML since it is difficult and unorthodox to do what you want with what you have?

Comment: I want to group the data inside the "data" tag an produce only one output for one group. Content of the data tag may contain child elements like "i" tag.

Comment: I understand what you are aiming at but can you alter the XML you already have with a grouping of the similar tags or are they from a system you cannot influence?

Comment: We are getting input from the system.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I need a generic solution that is you are selecting "p" tag in the key assign process it may be any tag like div,h2 or any tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="data"
          use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"
       select="key('kFollowing',generate-id())[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="data" mode="group">
  <data>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"
     select="key('kFollowing',
                 generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[1])
                 )/node()"/>
  </data>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="data/node()" mode="group">
   <xsl:if test="not(position() = 1)"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*/*[not(self::p)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <p>Sample data 1</p>
    <data>1</data>
    <data>2</data>
    <data>3</data>
    <data>4</data>
    <p>Sample data 2</p>
    <p>Sample data 3</p>
    <data>a</data>
    <data>b</data>
    <data>c
        <i>d</i>e
    </data>
    <data>d</data>
    <p>Sample data 4</p>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <p>Sample data 1</p>
   <data>1 2 3 4</data>
   <p>Sample data 2</p>
   <p>Sample data 3</p>
   <data>a b c <i>d</i> e d</data>
   <p>Sample data 4</p>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I need a generic solution that is you are selecting "p" tag in the key assign process it may be any tag like div,h2 or any tag.

Comment: @Muthu, Your current question is completely answered. Please accept this answer (by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer). Please, ask any further questions as ... well, new, SO questions. Of course, when asking them, you need to make the question precise and eliminate ambiguity as much as possible, so that people answering those, will not have to resort to guessing and produce 99% not what you wanted.